# Outlook connected to exchange does not send email

Tags: exchange, outlook

I have multiple machines with Outlook 2010 connected to RackSpace hosted exchange server. Everything works fine, but emails send after a while since outlook started will not leave the outbox. Clicking Send & Receive will display the progress bar at 100% completed with no errors, but is not really finishing. The Cancel All button is still active.

The emails in the outbox are bold & italic, so ready to be send.

When I close outlook and start it again, the mails are sent immediately without problems.

I have tried the following:

- Checked if there are any third party addins: only Microsoft Add ins
- Checked if the virus scanner is blocking anything, but McAfee is not doing this.
- Checked and Repaired the .ost file
- Increased the server time-out from 30 seconds to 60 seconds

Nothing helped. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try taking one of the affected clients out of cached mode and see if that resolves the problem. If it does you can focus your troubleshooting on cached mode.